# How to stop app rstudio loading on localhost:8787

Tags: webserver, r, localhost, rstudio

(Tag recommendations welcome, I do not know how to properly categorise or tag my issue)

Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a mystery. When I visit localhost:8787 I am taken to the rstudio login screen:

[image]

I do not know what process is hosting the rstudio app at localhost:8787. A few weeks back I DID  run a docker container for rstudio that was accessed via localhost:8787. However, that container has been stopped, deleted and in fact, I have deleted all docker images:

(No containers here)

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Not even any images to run:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

I found a post after a search for 'how to tell what process is hosted on localhost'. I was not sure of what search term to use here.

Following some searching I ran this command in the terminal:

```
netstat -aon | grep 8787
```

Which returned this:

```
netstat -aon | grep 8787
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41490         TIME_WAIT   timewait (47.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41212         TIME_WAIT   timewait (16.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41402         TIME_WAIT   timewait (39.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41344         TIME_WAIT   timewait (32.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41144         TIME_WAIT   timewait (7.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41340         TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.84/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41090         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41096         TIME_WAIT   timewait (1.74/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41200         TIME_WAIT   timewait (14.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41556         TIME_WAIT   timewait (56.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41080         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41356         TIME_WAIT   timewait (33.85/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41240         TIME_WAIT   timewait (19.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41492         TIME_WAIT   timewait (48.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41294         TIME_WAIT   timewait (26.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41078         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41324         TIME_WAIT   timewait (29.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41286         TIME_WAIT   timewait (25.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41436         TIME_WAIT   timewait (41.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41388         TIME_WAIT   timewait (37.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41282         TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41306         TIME_WAIT   timewait (27.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41198         TIME_WAIT   timewait (14.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41564         TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41170         TIME_WAIT   timewait (10.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41548         TIME_WAIT   timewait (55.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41520         TIME_WAIT   timewait (51.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41216         TIME_WAIT   timewait (16.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41348         TIME_WAIT   timewait (32.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41394         TIME_WAIT   timewait (38.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41118         TIME_WAIT   timewait (4.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41226         TIME_WAIT   timewait (17.81/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41298         TIME_WAIT   timewait (26.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41130         TIME_WAIT   timewait (5.81/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41544         TIME_WAIT   timewait (54.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41498         TIME_WAIT   timewait (48.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41450         TIME_WAIT   timewait (43.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41562         TIME_WAIT   timewait (56.95/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41202         TIME_WAIT   timewait (14.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41092         TIME_WAIT   timewait (1.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41106         TIME_WAIT   timewait (2.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41196         TIME_WAIT   timewait (14.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41352         TIME_WAIT   timewait (33.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41574         TIME_WAIT   timewait (58.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41554         TIME_WAIT   timewait (55.93/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41272         TIME_WAIT   timewait (23.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41338         TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41560         TIME_WAIT   timewait (56.94/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41390         TIME_WAIT   timewait (37.93/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41452         TIME_WAIT   timewait (43.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41346         TIME_WAIT   timewait (32.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41570         TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41254         TIME_WAIT   timewait (21.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41486         TIME_WAIT   timewait (47.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41350         TIME_WAIT   timewait (32.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41382         TIME_WAIT   timewait (36.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41110         TIME_WAIT   timewait (3.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41374         TIME_WAIT   timewait (35.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41274         TIME_WAIT   timewait (23.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41270         TIME_WAIT   timewait (23.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41172         TIME_WAIT   timewait (11.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41244         TIME_WAIT   timewait (20.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41482         TIME_WAIT   timewait (46.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41370         TIME_WAIT   timewait (35.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41208         TIME_WAIT   timewait (15.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41578         TIME_WAIT   timewait (58.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41292         TIME_WAIT   timewait (25.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41114         TIME_WAIT   timewait (3.77/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41156         TIME_WAIT   timewait (9.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41460         TIME_WAIT   timewait (44.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41168         TIME_WAIT   timewait (10.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41310         TIME_WAIT   timewait (28.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41440         TIME_WAIT   timewait (42.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41160         TIME_WAIT   timewait (9.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41552         TIME_WAIT   timewait (55.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41584         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.94/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41234         TIME_WAIT   timewait (18.81/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41132         TIME_WAIT   timewait (6.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41366         TIME_WAIT   timewait (34.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41458         TIME_WAIT   timewait (44.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41456         TIME_WAIT   timewait (44.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41404         TIME_WAIT   timewait (39.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41084         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.54/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41386         TIME_WAIT   timewait (37.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41210         TIME_WAIT   timewait (15.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41098         TIME_WAIT   timewait (1.74/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41134         TIME_WAIT   timewait (6.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41320         TIME_WAIT   timewait (29.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41514         TIME_WAIT   timewait (50.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41312         TIME_WAIT   timewait (28.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41120         TIME_WAIT   timewait (4.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41082         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41568         TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.94/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41462         TIME_WAIT   timewait (44.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41566         TIME_WAIT   timewait (57.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41360         TIME_WAIT   timewait (34.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41104         TIME_WAIT   timewait (2.75/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41536         TIME_WAIT   timewait (53.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41586         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.96/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41326         TIME_WAIT   timewait (29.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41276         TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41378         TIME_WAIT   timewait (36.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41540         TIME_WAIT   timewait (54.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41330         TIME_WAIT   timewait (30.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41392         TIME_WAIT   timewait (38.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41384         TIME_WAIT   timewait (37.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41488         TIME_WAIT   timewait (47.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41162         TIME_WAIT   timewait (9.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41238         TIME_WAIT   timewait (19.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41504         TIME_WAIT   timewait (49.90/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41194         TIME_WAIT   timewait (13.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41300         TIME_WAIT   timewait (26.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41242         TIME_WAIT   timewait (19.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41476         TIME_WAIT   timewait (46.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41572         TIME_WAIT   timewait (58.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41204         TIME_WAIT   timewait (15.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41538         TIME_WAIT   timewait (53.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41176         TIME_WAIT   timewait (11.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41108         TIME_WAIT   timewait (3.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41150         TIME_WAIT   timewait (8.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41480         TIME_WAIT   timewait (46.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41420         TIME_WAIT   timewait (40.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41532         TIME_WAIT   timewait (53.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41534         TIME_WAIT   timewait (53.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41232         TIME_WAIT   timewait (18.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41088         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.74/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41576         TIME_WAIT   timewait (58.94/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41252         TIME_WAIT   timewait (21.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41124         TIME_WAIT   timewait (5.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41398         TIME_WAIT   timewait (38.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41526         TIME_WAIT   timewait (52.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41308         TIME_WAIT   timewait (27.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41468         TIME_WAIT   timewait (45.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41220         TIME_WAIT   timewait (17.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41102         TIME_WAIT   timewait (2.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41246         TIME_WAIT   timewait (20.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41296         TIME_WAIT   timewait (26.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41542         TIME_WAIT   timewait (54.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41218         TIME_WAIT   timewait (16.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41508         TIME_WAIT   timewait (50.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41412         TIME_WAIT   timewait (40.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41258         TIME_WAIT   timewait (21.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41336         TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41328         TIME_WAIT   timewait (30.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41512         TIME_WAIT   timewait (50.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41380         TIME_WAIT   timewait (36.85/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41364         TIME_WAIT   timewait (34.85/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41288         TIME_WAIT   timewait (25.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41256         TIME_WAIT   timewait (21.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41582         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41186         TIME_WAIT   timewait (12.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41400         TIME_WAIT   timewait (39.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41302         TIME_WAIT   timewait (27.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41368         TIME_WAIT   timewait (35.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41550         TIME_WAIT   timewait (55.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41182         TIME_WAIT   timewait (12.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41158         TIME_WAIT   timewait (9.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41484         TIME_WAIT   timewait (47.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41112         TIME_WAIT   timewait (3.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41332         TIME_WAIT   timewait (30.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41580         TIME_WAIT   timewait (59.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41410         TIME_WAIT   timewait (40.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41524         TIME_WAIT   timewait (52.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41206         TIME_WAIT   timewait (15.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41224         TIME_WAIT   timewait (17.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41248         TIME_WAIT   timewait (20.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41448         TIME_WAIT   timewait (43.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41154         TIME_WAIT   timewait (8.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41362         TIME_WAIT   timewait (34.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41354         TIME_WAIT   timewait (33.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41230         TIME_WAIT   timewait (18.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41076         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41116         TIME_WAIT   timewait (4.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41496         TIME_WAIT   timewait (48.90/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41188         TIME_WAIT   timewait (13.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41164         TIME_WAIT   timewait (10.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41446         TIME_WAIT   timewait (42.88/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41236         TIME_WAIT   timewait (19.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41438         TIME_WAIT   timewait (41.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41322         TIME_WAIT   timewait (29.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41260         TIME_WAIT   timewait (22.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41268         TIME_WAIT   timewait (23.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41516         TIME_WAIT   timewait (51.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41304         TIME_WAIT   timewait (27.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41192         TIME_WAIT   timewait (13.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41406         TIME_WAIT   timewait (39.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41316         TIME_WAIT   timewait (28.84/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41278         TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41472         TIME_WAIT   timewait (45.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41126         TIME_WAIT   timewait (5.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41432         TIME_WAIT   timewait (41.59/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41136         TIME_WAIT   timewait (6.76/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41358         TIME_WAIT   timewait (33.85/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41342         TIME_WAIT   timewait (31.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41140         TIME_WAIT   timewait (7.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41264         TIME_WAIT   timewait (22.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41222         TIME_WAIT   timewait (17.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41262         TIME_WAIT   timewait (22.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41470         TIME_WAIT   timewait (45.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41454         TIME_WAIT   timewait (43.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41152         TIME_WAIT   timewait (8.77/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41558         TIME_WAIT   timewait (56.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41138         TIME_WAIT   timewait (6.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41122         TIME_WAIT   timewait (4.77/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41334         TIME_WAIT   timewait (30.84/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41142         TIME_WAIT   timewait (7.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41510         TIME_WAIT   timewait (50.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41478         TIME_WAIT   timewait (46.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41502         TIME_WAIT   timewait (49.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41266         TIME_WAIT   timewait (22.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41314         TIME_WAIT   timewait (28.83/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41522         TIME_WAIT   timewait (51.93/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41178         TIME_WAIT   timewait (11.79/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41146         TIME_WAIT   timewait (7.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41434         TIME_WAIT   timewait (41.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41280         TIME_WAIT   timewait (24.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41128         TIME_WAIT   timewait (5.80/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41474         TIME_WAIT   timewait (45.89/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41376         TIME_WAIT   timewait (36.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41228         TIME_WAIT   timewait (18.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41418         TIME_WAIT   timewait (40.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41442         TIME_WAIT   timewait (42.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41190         TIME_WAIT   timewait (13.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41530         TIME_WAIT   timewait (52.92/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41250         TIME_WAIT   timewait (20.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41396         TIME_WAIT   timewait (38.86/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41372         TIME_WAIT   timewait (35.87/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41546         TIME_WAIT   timewait (54.93/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41528         TIME_WAIT   timewait (52.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41500         TIME_WAIT   timewait (49.60/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41180         TIME_WAIT   timewait (12.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41184         TIME_WAIT   timewait (12.78/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41506         TIME_WAIT   timewait (49.91/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41166         TIME_WAIT   timewait (10.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41518         TIME_WAIT   timewait (51.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41494         TIME_WAIT   timewait (48.61/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41214         TIME_WAIT   timewait (16.58/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41094         TIME_WAIT   timewait (1.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41086         TIME_WAIT   timewait (0.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41148         TIME_WAIT   timewait (8.56/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41290         TIME_WAIT   timewait (25.82/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41174         TIME_WAIT   timewait (11.57/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41100         TIME_WAIT   timewait (2.55/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          127.0.0.1:41444         TIME_WAIT   timewait (42.87/0/0)
```

What's happening here?! Why is localhost:8787 serving rstudio app and how can I stop it?

EDIT:
Output from `dpkg -l | grep rstudio` and `systemctl list-units --type service | grep -i rstudio` below per comments:

```
dpkg -l | grep rstudio
ii  rstudio                                    1.3.1093                                         amd64        RStudio
ii  rstudio-server                             1.3.1093                                         amd64        RStudio Server
```

and

```
systemctl list-units --type service | grep -i rstudio
rstudio-server.service                                loaded active running RStudio Server
```

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep rstudio` and `systemctl list-units --type service | grep -i rstudio` to the question.

Comment: Hi @N0rbert OK, output added. Let me know if there's any other info I can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable [RStudio Server](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#rstudio-server) temporarily, then disable its service by

```
sudo systemctl disable rstudio-server.service
```

If you want to remove RStudio Server completely, then uninstall it with

```
sudo apt-get purge rstudio-server
```

Comment: Thanks Norbert. I have installed rstudio as a standalone app, or at least I thought so. Coming from Mac, I used to also have the rstudio app. While using this stand alone app nothing was hosted on e.g. localhost. Does this mean that this is not the case with rstudio app on Ubuntu?

Comment: There are two editions - RStudio and RStudio Server. The first is standalone app. The second is server-based, you can use it in the local network.

Comment: Welp, using the first command did not halt the issue but the purge command did - thank you! I just checked, and the stand alone app is still working fine. I wonder if I accidentally installed rstudio server while trying to figure out how to install the regular app. Anyway, this is fixed now, thank you very much!

Comment: What is `systemctl list-units --type service | grep -i rstudio` doing exactly? Specifically `systemctl list-units` ?

Comment: SystemCtrl itself shows and controls the services/daemons. See man-page for systemctl on local system by `man systemctl` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/systemctl.1.html). Then we parse its output by `grep` to filter *rstudio*-named lines.

Comment: Thank you! I will do some reading on systemctl